Tick functions not working in 14.0.0?
Consider the code
tickFunc = 
  MapAt[Reverse, {All, 3}]@*
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
    "TicksLength" -> {.01, .005}];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc[##] &, None}, {tickFunc[##] &, None}}]

Which should give a plot with customized ticks, given by tickFunc, which basically makes ticks point outwards, with respect to the frame, as follows

This worked fine in previous versions. However, as of version 14.0.0, the plot initially behaves correctly, but then automatically changes to the default ticks (crossing the axes)

Why does this happen? Is there a way of fixing this?

a workaround: add the option PlotHighlighting -> None.

@kglr, interestingly, when you zoom in/out, the crossing ticks appear again, and you can only get rid of them by resizing the plot ...

@kglr Also, when I export it by right-clicking and "saving graphics as", the ticks appear (at least in PDF).

The crossing ticks appear as soon as the cursor enters the graphics.

Ticks have always been buggy in MA...

@yarchik I see. This function seems to work fine in 13.3.0.

Do you have a $PlotTheme set?  When I try with 14.0.0 I have no problem, ticks only on the outside.  Try, for example, GraphicsRow[  Table[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True,     FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc[##] &, None}, {tickFunc[##] &, None}},     PlotTheme -> theme, ImageSize -> 400],   {theme, {"Minimal", "Monochrome", "Detailed", "Scientific" }}],  ImageSize -> 2000  ]

@evanb I'm afraid the issue remains in all themes.

No problem (both on screen and saved graphics image) with "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)".
